SmtpClient in 4.5 with gmail account
Ive set 2FA for my account and set apppassword. Still getting the same error:
Unable to read data from the transport connection: net_io_connectionclosed.

Port I`m using is: 465
MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
message.IsBodyHtml = true;
message.From = new MailAddress(smtp.FromEmail, smtp.FromName);
message.To.Add(new MailAddress(dto.To));
message.Subject = dto.Subject;
message.Body = dto.Body;

using (var client = new SmtpClient(smtp.Host, smtp.Port.Value))
{
    client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(smtp.UserName, smtp.Password);
    client.EnableSsl = true;

    try
    {
        client.Send(message);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
}

How I can use .NET 4.5 HttpClient to send emails using gmail account?

Does this answer your question? SMTPException : Unable to read data from the transport connection: net_io_connectionclosed

if that doesnt help can you add your code please.

No it doesnt help. Ive added my code.

Solution is to switch to port 587.
